# Where are the javadoc comments for the decompiled minecraft source?

Tags: java, javadoc, minecraft, decompiler, minecraft-forge

I used Forge to decompile Minecraft 1.8. In the source, I see the added Forge methods and modifications all commented properly. However, the vanilla code for Minecraft isn't commented at all. I know MCP is used to decompile Minecraft, but I thought it added javadoc comments to all the methods. I'm wondering if there's a way to find the javadoc and attach it to my project.

Comment: Java doc is not copied into the Java byte codes.  You'll need the actual source code for that.

Comment: According to this MCP page under v6.0, "Added javadoc comments to the decompiled sourcecode.": http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Programs_and_editors/Minecraft_Coder_Pack

Comment: It's been a LONG time since I looked at Minecraft's source code, (probably haven't since beta), but I think there should be comments. If there aren't, just look at tutorials for what to modify, or just work on reading the code, adding comments where you want them. (Much of the code is straightforward, like crafting, blocks, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. MCP is an ongoing project, and the team hasn't fully found all fields and methods, but they release mappings and CSV's (as referred to by Antimony) every night. When setting up the workspace using Forge, I specified in my build.gradle under 'minecraft':

```
mappings = "snapshot_20141224" // originally some 'nodoc' version :(
```

This specified the version of the MCP mappings I wanted to stick in my minecraft source. When I decompiled again, MCP fetched the correct mappings and voila, the methods that were previously uncommented were then commented.

You can find a list of all mappings snapshots and CSV exports here: http://export.mcpbot.bspk.rs/

Answer (score 4):

Comments aren't present in the compiled bytecode at all. So the best the decompiler can do is autogenerate a useless Javadoc based on the method signature, but most won't even bother because such Javadocs are obviously useless.

Edit: I looked into MCP, and apparently, after decompiling, it applies a bunch of manually chosen renames and they have descriptions.

For example, one entry in `fields.csv` says

```
field_100013_f,isPotionDurationMax,0,"True if potion effect duration is at maximum, false otherwise."
```

So presumably, this means that it will rename `field_100013_f` to `isPotionDurationMax` and generate a comment with the description "True if potion effect duration is at maximum, false otherwise.". So in this case it isn't magically recovering the original comments and names because that is impossible. Instead, it is displaying user chosen names and comments that have been provided as part of MCP.

Of course, since this is relying on manually provided information, it will only fix methods and fields for which people have provided descriptions.

There is also an option in MCP to strip out comments entirely. I'm not positive on when this happens, but presumably it is done to make patches apply more reliably. You (i.e. Forge) may have been using this option.